# How to create an interactive pie chart with javascript, html, css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

How to create a pie chart widget where the user can change the distribution of the pie chart by dragging the borders of the wedges?

Is there a package with such a widget in react?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. When the user drags a border of a segment how are segment sizes recalculated. Please show us the code you have so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Personally i have never seen a pie with draggable border to change the distribution. I have worked with **ApexCharts** (https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/pie-charts/update-donut/). Each part of the pie is basicaly a number so, you can create for example a slider for each part and dynamicly update the part of the chart.